# How to open AppCompatActivity class?

Tags: java, android, android-studio

I wanna see the AppCompatActivity class methods and objects In android studio

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity{
```

Comment: which OS , do you have?

Answer (score 1):

Press hot key **Ctrl+N** then type class that you want to view its source code. Remember check ***check box*** in search class dialog as well.

Or hold **Ctrl** key then left click on **AppCompatActivity** class.

Answer (score 1):

Put cursor on **AppCompatActivity** then press **CTRL + B** or Right click on **AppCompatActivity** >> go to >> declaration.

Answer (score 1):

If you have MacOS, click on `AppCompatActivity` while holding <kbd>command</kbd>.

Comment: Or press command + B while the cursor is on AppCompatActivity.